# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema con un `crm` que estoy elaborando... les agradezco de antemano.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/core/Database.php:17 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/core/Model.php(168):
>   Database::query('SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #1
>   /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/core/Auth.php(52):
>   Model::where(Array, 0) #2
>   /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/Controladores/loginController.php(29):
>   Auth::login('rod', 'admin') #3
>   /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/index.php(32):
>   loginController::autenticar(Object(stdClass)) #4 {main} thrown in
>   /home/o0nsciatt5i4/public_html/crm/core/Database.php on line 17

```
Database.php 


<?php 

class Database {
    static $db;
    static $error;
    static function init($config){
        self::$db = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$config['host'].';port='.$config['port'].';dbname='.$config['name'],
                            $config['user'],
                            $config['pass'],
                            array(
                                \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
                            );
        self::query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }

    static function query($query, $params = null, $fetch = true){        
**Line 17**       $reponse = self::$db->prepare($query);        
        $reponse->execute($params);          
        if ($reponse->errorInfo()[0]!='00000'){
            static::$error= $reponse->errorInfo();
            return false;
        }

        if ($fetch) {
            $res=$reponse->fetchAll();           
            return $res;
        }
        return $reponse;
    }

    static function lastInsertId($name = null)
    {
       return self::$db->lastInsertId($name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Esto es un error de PHP, no es ni de Linux ni de cPanel. Pulsa en [edit] para poner el código PHP donde se produce el error y poner también la etiqueta correcta en la pregunta que debería ser `php`

Comment: Parece que no estás ejecutando Database::init() para crear la conexión.